# Cannot access 192.168.xx.yyy from Android device

Tags: android, apache

I'm running Apache in Mac Os 10.8 and this is my httpd.conf (a part of it):

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"

# 
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect 
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories). 
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
# features.  
#
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    #Allow from all
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
    #Allow from 192.168.0.102
    #Allow from 192.168.0.104
    #Allow from ::1
    #Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```

In `<Directory />`if I change `Deny from all` to `Allow from all` I get `Not found. The requested URL / was not found on this server`when accessing from my device (testing in the browser the ip: 192.168.0.103 which is my localhost wifi ip). But if is set `Deny from all` then I get `Forbidden`. I don't know how to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know you are, but asking, are you sure that both your device are in same network ?

Comment: Yes (I just have one device and one computer :) )

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a lot of hours of debugging, finally I've fixed it. The problem was my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I had this dummy host pre-installed. If you read the comments `The first VirtualHost seection is usedfor all requests that do not match a ServerName or ServerAlias...`. So I've removed it, and now my first virtual host is my own directory (it must be the first one, after it you can put other virtual hosts directives).